# Error SQL syntax when execute MySQL query in VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net, row-number

in my case, i just want to get the missing number in my data.
i have a MySQL query that executed well in query editor.
but when i put that query to my VB.Net project, its return an error

when i use this code, its return an error "Fatal error encountered during command execution."

```vb
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COALESCE(MIN(norow),0) " & _
                  "FROM ( " & _
                  "   SELECT @norow:=@norow+1 AS norow, " & _
                  "           nocst " & _
                  "   FROM cst, (SELECT @norow:=0) T " & _
                  "   ORDER BY nocst " & _
                  ") X " & _
                  "WHERE norow<>nocst "
```

and when i use mysqlparameter, also return an error
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':= ....."

```vb
cmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@norow", MySqlDbType.Double)).Value = 0
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COALESCE(MIN(norow),0) " & _
                  "FROM ( " & _
                  "   SELECT @norow:=@norow+1 AS norow, " & _
                  "           nocst " & _
                  "   FROM cst " & _
                  "   ORDER BY nocst " & _
                  ") X " & _
                  "WHERE norow<>nocst "
```

can someone explain why its error and what the solve.
i just want to single execute by mysql result without for in vb.
thank you

Comment: Note that VB supports multiline `String` literals in recent versions so you should get rid of that concatenation in the name of readability.  It also means that you don't have to be careful to include spaces where you logically want a line break.  I don't think you've missed any spaces in this case but plenty of people do. In older versions you can still use XML literals, so that type of concatenation is never required.

Comment: that querys run well on sql editor